# How to simulate or inject an error into my process

Tags: c, windows, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm trying to test some code that handles STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN in Windows. I'm not sure how I can go about testing this error and if it is possible to send this error to the process or if I can create a scenario that will cause this. Any help would be great, even just a code snippet that causes this error reliably.

Comment: you need use [Buffer Security Check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-buffer-security-check?view=vs-2017) and overwrite *security cookie*. with msvc for example : `void dmsb()
{
 static volatile UCHAR z = 0;
 void* stack = alloca(z);
 memset(stack, 0, (ptrdiff_t)_AddressOfReturnAddress() - (ptrdiff_t)stack);
}`. with Buffer Security Check you got `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN` if execute this function. without it (`/GS-`) - all will be ok

Comment: Status 0xC0000409 (`STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`) should be thought of as "STATUS_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE" in Windows 8+. In user mode, the [`__fastfail`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/fastfail?view=vs-2017) intrinsic kills the process with a second-chance exception (debugger only) that uses this status code. The parameter (subcode) tells us what kind of failure it is. `FAST_FAIL_LEGACY_GS_VIOLATION` (0) is for the previous usage of this status. C `abort` uses `FAST_FAIL_FATAL_APP_EXIT` (7). In the kernel, a fast fail is bug check 0x139, `KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE`.